# Can you replace multiple pattern matches from one string using regexp_replace?

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

Here is a sample string:
Year,Quarter,Month,text1,text2,Department,BU,text3,text4,Job,Grade,Pay,Location,text5,text6,

I need to remove all occurrences of the random texts. Rules are:

1. The random texts always come in a pair, one after another.
2. The first of the two texts always begin with the word “namesa” however the length is unpredictable, but the second one follows no such pattern. Example, text1 could be “namesa-their duty 505”, text3 could be “namesa-silver lane near me”, text5 could be “namesa-regexp 101 challenge”. Text2, text4, text6 are completely unpredictable.
3. None of these texts contain a comma. They only end in a comma.
4. The number of times this whole pattern repeats is unpredictable.

select ('Year,Quarter,Month,namesa-their duty 505,text2,Department,BU,namesa-silver lane near me,text4,Job,Grade,Pay,Location,namesa-regexp 101 challenge,text6,') from dual;

For the above input, my output should be:
Year,Quarter,Month,Department,BU,Job,Grade,Pay,Location,

Basically, we need to locate the word “namesa” - start from there, go through two commas, remove everything from namesa through the second comma, then repeat the same thing again for the rest of the string. I am at a loss how to do this in regular expressions.

Comment: Just to make sure: In your sample inputs, you show the comma as a field TERMINATOR rather than SEPARATOR. Specifically, at least when the last two "tokens" in the string are a pair that must be removed, the input string **ends in a comma**. Is that the case in your actual data? @eaolson's answer depends on that assumption. If the assumption is not correct, that can be fixed easily, but you must say so.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a comma-delimited string of tokens and you're trying to replace every token that starts with "namesa" and remove it and the following token? Try this:

```
regexp_replace(col1, 'namesa[^,]*,[^,]*,', '')
```

So that breaks down to:

1. The string "namesa"
2. Zero or more characters that are not a comma
3. A comma (ending the first token)
4. Zero or more characters that are not a comma
5. A comma (ending the second token)

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36a80/90)

Comment: Almost correct. The only issue I see is the possibility that the last pair is at the very end of the string, in which case there will not be a comma at the end, and the whole pair will not be removed. Easy to fix: replace the second comma in the regular expression with the alternation `(,|$)` (meaning, the pair should be followed either by comma or by the end of the string). Actually I'll go ahead and edit your solution; this is the explanation.

Comment: Actually, if you'll notice, sush's question has the terminating comma on the desired output.

Comment: Oh, you are correct, I didn't notice that. Let me undo my edit!